# Multicols{3} problem - how to reduce space between columns?

Tags: spacing, multicol, multicolumn

I want to reduce the space between columns in multicols
I use `\setlength{\columnsep}{<space>}` but it reduces the space between the 2nd column and the 3rd column only
How to make it reduce the space after the 1st column too in case of using `multicols{3}`

Comment: You have to pass some value: `0pt` for example.

Comment: Yes I do for sure!

Comment: Ow, now the edited code shows the space.

Comment: Maybe you are willing to provide a MWE...

Comment: since you are getting a different result than the answers provided, it seems likely that you are using this in a different way, so your context is necessary to determine why that is happening.

Answer (score 4):

The following example removes the inter column space by setting `\columnsep`, which affects all inter column spaces:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\lipsum[1]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

BTW, have fun reading it. ☺

Or with rules:

```
\setlength{\columnrulewidth}{1pt}
```

> [image: Result with rules]

Also negative values are possible, e.g.:

```
\setlength{\columnsep}{-10pt}
```

> [image: Result with negative columnwidth]

Comment: Okay what if I want to reduce the space not by using -10pt instead of 0pt? It doesn't reduce equally!

Comment: @user77565 The `\columnsep` is used for both inter column spaces. The value can even be negative. (Why would someone want to have a negative value here?)

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek To annoy the readers?

Comment: @Heiko The negative value is very useful in some cases (for examples two face-to-face sections), where the resulting space is actually positive. (Right now I'm using `-6em`.)